# How can I see the SQL call to the Db done by NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

How can I see the SQL call generated and passed to Db by NHibernate?

I have in my hibernate.cfg.xml file this line:

```
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Hard to believe this was real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried seting the "show_sql" config entry to `true`?

Comment: You are right Mitch. I cahnged it. But I have missed the fact that I had to Rebuild my solution to make that xml changes active. So to set that to True worked fine! Thx!

Comment: Check out the format_sql property to, which makes your sql output look nice and pretty.